# Python & Google Places API | Want to get all Restaurants at a specific postion

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-places-api, google-places

I want to get all restaurants in London by using python 3.5 and the module `googleplaces` with the Google Places API. I read the `googleplaces` documentation and searched here, but I don't get it. Here is my code so far:

```
from googleplaces import GooglePlaces, types, lang

API_KEY = 'XXXCODEXXX'

google_places = GooglePlaces(API_KEY)

query_result = google_places.nearby_search(
    location='London', keyword='Restaurants',
    radius=1000, types=[types.TYPE_RESTAURANT])

if query_result.has_attributions:
print query_result.html_attributions


for place in query_result.places:
    place.get_details()
    print place.rating
```

The code doesn't work. What can I do to get a list with all restaurants in this area?

Comment: What is happening when you run your code? Are you getting any errors, or what?

Comment: sorry. I forgot this information. I get this error: IndentationError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'.

Comment: can someone help me?

Comment: Yeah I can try. So what specifically is happening with your code? Are there errors or what?

Comment: The example code you're working with uses Python 2.x syntax, and you're using the Python 3.5 interpreter. So to start with, you can either change the code or change the interpreter.

Answer (score 4):

It'll be better if you drop the `keyword` parameter, `types` already searches for restaurants.

Bear in mind the Places API (as other Google Maps APIs) is not a database, it will not return all results that match. Actually returns only 20, and you can get an extra 40 or so, but that's all.

If I'm reading the [GooglePlaces](https://github.com/slimkrazy/python-google-places/blob/master/googleplaces/__init__.py) correctly, your code will send an API request such like:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=51.507351,-0.127758&radius=1000&types=restaurant&keyword=Restaurants&key=YOUR_API_KEY

If you just drop the `keyword` parameter, it'll be like:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=51.507351,-0.127758&radius=1000&types=restaurant&key=YOUR_API_KEY

The difference is subtle: `keyword=Restaurants` will make the API match results that have the word "Restaurants" in their name, address, etc. Some of these may not be restaurants (and will be discarded), while some actual restaurants may not have the word "Restaurants" in them.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change city value by latitude and longitude and it's not necessary to put the keyword because you are specified that on Type try to put this code it's work for me :

```
query_result = google_places.nearby_search(
        lat_lng={'lat': 46.1667, 'lng': -1.15}, 
        radius=5000,
        types=[types.TYPE_RESTAURANT] or [types.TYPE_CAFE] or [type.TYPE_BAR] or [type.TYPE_CASINO])
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing missing is as the error says, parentheses (). Your code should be

```
if query_result.has_attributions:
    print (query_result.html_attributions)
```